# xdebug not showing in output of `php -m` but shows in phpinfo

Tags: php, xdebug

I have the opposite problem as described in this users [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190624/xdebug-shows-up-in-command-line-php-m-but-not-in-phpinfo).

If I execute `php -m` then there is no xdebug showing up, but it shows in the phpinfo.

[image: phpinfo]

According to the documentation it should show up twice if I execute `php -m`, once under `[PHP Modules]` and once under `[Zend Modules]`.

But `php -m | grep -i xdebug` returns nothing.

This is my setup in the php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension='/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/xdebug.so'
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.renite_enable = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = '/var/log'

[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

...
```

I figured out that xdebug works nevertheless, but I am still curious.

Comment: Sounds like they're using different php.ini files?

Comment: Jonnix might be right. Depending on your environment, CLI configuration is usually in different file. Try to see if you have `/etc/php/X.Y.Z/cli/php.ini` file.

Comment: @Haru, thx for the hint. Yes the file `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` exists. I entered `zend_extension='/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/xdebug.so'` at the top and restarted apache and now it shows up twice as it should! Thx. Please make an answer so I can accpet it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your environment, CLI configuration is usually in a different file. Try to see if you have `/etc/php/X.Y.Z/cli/php.ini` file and add this at the top:

```
zend_extension='/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/xdebug.so'
```

Replace the path with the path of your `xdebug.so` file.

You can find it out by executing `locate xdebug.so`